# WSO2 Identity Server 5.0.0 boolean claims

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I am trying to add custom boolean claims to my user profiles. I added claim in the http://wso2.org/oidc/claim dialect and then added the necessary mapping in the http://wso2.org/claims and made the claim supported by default. I want to store boolean value in that custom claim (true/false). Once I open some identity I see a blank value for that claim. If I store the value "true" and save the profile, I receive a checkbox with tick. If I then go and update some other field of the same identity and click save, the boolean value is preserved and I am still seeing the checkbox with the tick (which represents the "true" value). Then I decided to uncheck the value for my custom boolean claim in order to store the "false" value for the claim. But once I clicked "save" button, I was no longer seeing the empty checkbox (which I expect to represent the "false" value). Instead I am seeing a blank field which expects value. At this moment if I try to call the user info endpoint, I am not retrieving the mentioned custom claim. In order to receive a false value for it, I need to go to the mentioned identity, explicitly type "false" and save the identity. After that I receive the "false" value for that claim. Then if for some reason someone goes after me and update another part of the identity, the "false" value for my custom claim is lost and I fall in the previous situation and I am not able to get the value for the custom claim, because it is not defined.
I am using "Account locked" claim and I am not able to observe such behavior with this claim. I suppose because it is a sort of special one, because it is used by the identity management.
Is there a way to workaround this situation? For the moment I made the claim "required" and you are not able to save the identity with an empty value for that claim (through the IS Admin Console).
Is this expected behavior when it comes to boolean claims in the WSO2 IS 5.0.0?

Answer (score 0):

This is the expected behavior. Claims can have any value (numeric, boolean, text etc.) and therefore Identity Server cannot identify the data type of the claim. However booleans are treated little bit different. Initially when you add the claim, it will be displayed as a text box as IS cannot decide the data type. Once you save the user profile adding either 'true' or 'false' as the value for the text box (for the very first time), then internally IS will identify this claim to be a boolean. From then onwards it will be displayed as a check box in the UI.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Once I enter 'false' value and save it, indeed it is displayed like an empty check box. But then if I edit other field of the identity and save again, the check box disappear and the claim is left blank. This is not the case if the entered value is true.

Comment: Yes, that is a bug in IS 5.0.0. However this is fixed when comes to IS 5.1.0 and 5.2.0. If you need this fixed on IS 5.0.0, I would be able to help you to patch the particular component.

Comment: That would be nice if you could provide me details how to patch the correct component in order to overcome the mentioned above behavior. By the way I am using IS 5.0.0 with SP1 installed. Do you think if I install Service Pack 2, the issue will be resolved, or I need specific other patch that should be applied on my system? Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you have the Service Pack 2 (WSO2-IS-5.0.0-SP02) for Identity Server which is the patch1546, then you can apply it and the issue is fixed with that.

Comment: Thanks for the provided information. Will try it out.